# Authenticated calls between Google App Engine services

Tags: google-app-engine

Authenticated calls between Google App Engine services

Is there a way to make Google App Engine services only callable within the App engine?

For example, I create service-a and service-b in my GAE.
By, default, service-a and service-b are public, so I can send requests to them without authentication.
I would like to make them unreachable from the public, but service-a and service-b can still communicate with each other.

Appreciate it if someone could help me with this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Identity Aware Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/concepts-overview) to secure your services and allow access only to the App Engine Service Account. The benefit of IAP is that you don't need to make any changes in you code to secure your service.

After your service is secured by IAP, you can call it by adding the **Authorization** header with the service account's **OIDC Token** as bearer value. This is pretty easy to do with almost any programming language. Take a look at [this link](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto#obtaining_an_oidc_token_for_the_default_service_account) to learn how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I personally find the learning curve for anything related to IAP to be very steep.

An easy way to create your own authentication is to do the following:

- Create a secret token and put it in the code of your services.
- When your service calls another one of your services, put the secret token in the header.
- The receiving service rejects calls that don't have your secret token.

Another way might be to look for the `X-Appengine-Inbound-Appid` header that Google adds.  See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/reference/request-response-headers

I haven't done that so you should verify that it would work.

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume your projects are "myprojectABC" and "myprojectDEF" and you want to allow request only for these projects.

ALLOWED_PROJECTS=["myprojectABC","myprojectDEF"]

ALLOWED_APS=["myprojectABC.appspot.com","myprojectDEF.appspot.com"]

1. Check for the header "X-Appengine-Inbound-Appid" if present and is in ALLOWED_PROJECTS, is authorized. if present and not in allowed project, then is not authorized.
2. If the header is not present, check header "X-Appengine-Taskname", if present check for the header "Referer" and make some comparisons with the allowed apps to authorize the request. Log the host header to understand how to convert and replace some parts ("-dot-") to build the project name.
3. if that header is not present check for the header "X-Appengine-Cron" if that header is present check for the header "Host" and if present check if is in ALLOWED_APPS, in that case authorize the request

if none of above, the request is from external site.

NOTE: The examples works for Python GAE, may be for other languages the notation of the app domain in 2) or 3) could change.